# Salesforce Data Extension POST/PUT Data Using JSON

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I tried to POST method to create a new record in salesforce data extension. I am using following method

POST /data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:MYEXTERNALKEY/rows

In header I am passing

```
content-type : application/json
Autherization : Bearer MyTOKEN
```

In Body I am passing data as

```
{
   "items": [{
      "EmailAddress":"john@gmail.com",
      "FirstName" : "John"
   },
   {
      "EmailAddress":"sam@gmail.com",
      "FirstName" : "Sam"
   }]
}
```

I am getting error as

```
{
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete this action.",
    "errorcode": 20002,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Can anybody help me on this? If this is permissions issue then help on how to assign Data extension permissions to this user.

I enabled `Email--> Subscribers-->Data Extensions--> Create,Update,Delete,Manage` permissions given under manage permissions. Still getting same response.

Comment: Looks like Your account lacks the privileges necessary to perform the request.... find more details on the error [20002] received here... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm

Answer (score 1):

I Think that you have issue with authorization bearer token. Give proper permissions while creating your access token. Documentation link follows.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest-permissions-and-scopes.htm